# Write form on AS400 system

Tags: mainframe

I need to write a form where I can get input from the user and save that data in DB2 present on my AS400 machine. RIght now, I am getting the default options provided by the mainframe like :

```
 1. Start PDM program development manager
 2. work with active jobs
 3. send message to HOLLE (operator)
 4. work with system status
 5. some games
 6. start chat (or enter    CHAT  in command line and press F4)
    (chat also viewable at http://www.holgerscherer.de/chatf.html )
 7. start TN5250-based WWW-browser
 8. show help (or enter HELP and command prompt)

10. display AS/400 main menu

90. Log off
```

How can I create my custom form for entering data.. 
Fields that I need in that form are :
Order id, Order Type & Order Details.

How can this be done? and how will I retrieve the data stored in AS400? I got only printing options over internet.

Comment: As horrible as it sounds - isn't there someone there who is actually familiar with using the mainframe system, and programming/db environment there? It really looks like you're slightly out of your depth, since that definitely doesn't look like a development environment of any sort, and AS400 is kind of esoteric these days.

Comment: yeah I just started working on this and have no experience at all in this. actually what I think after researching a bit is that either we need to write a script/ maybe this can be done using datasets but I am not sure whether these are right approaches even as there is very little documentation available on net regarding this issue

Comment: To add to @JourneymanGeek your also asking in a community full of young blood, We use it where I work but most of our devs are 40-50 years old and grew up in this industry with it. IBM still offer training courses for this, It's probably going to be your only option.

Comment: AS400 is not a mainframe (zOS - TSO), On the mainframe there is rexx - ISPF for this sort of thing. I do not know what the AS400 offers. Tou would also have the option of connecting to AS400 DB2 via OSBC / JDBC drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, hopefully this is not too, too late for you.

You don't say if you have any resources, at all.

And you're on the wrong website looking for us dinosaurs. We're all mostly offshore on this really lovely island in a special park. You know the **park**.

We don't have no **superuser**'s, we have **qsecofr**.

Here comes a whole kettle of fish, and keywords and commands and buzzwords to google you in the right direction on ibm's website.

Know mention of any paper manuals for the system and software development ?  Maybe on someone's closet or book shelf or the back of the computer room. Or if any software compilers are available in **C**, or **COBOL**, or **RPG** on your system. Or if any dinosaurs are still somewhere down the hall or basking in the break room, to ask questions of.

Fear not, based upon your vague job specification, let us assume you truely need only raw data entry -- no proofing nor any validation, just type and dump.

***Well, there's an app for that.***

And tons of resources, a whole library of reference manuals, a set for each and every major version of the OS. Yep, a lot of trees /forests died for them there pseudo-mainframes.  Since that library is online at ibm.com I leave it to you to google their website with the search term

**site:ibm.com +as/400 +manuals**

Or iseries instead of as/400.  Particularly noteworthy are the series of books known as the "**redbooks**" -- tips and tricks and some samples.

But, you have no time for reading through 81/2" - 11" - 3" thick manuals. Although the **redbooks** are mostly 1/4". Even though they're online and also **downloadable** as 5 MB **pdf**'s to your laptop for late night entertainment when you have trouble getting to sleep.

Let's assume that your system still has the basic development facilities.  You will need the book on ***data definitions ( DDS )*** so you can define a fixed length record layout of fields for a physical file, yes, as opposed to a logical file ( index over that physical file ). You will want the file to have a **primary index** so define **key fields** for customer number or order number or what have you. That's where **PDM** enters the picture, using this online source code editor management system.

All programs make access of files via it's internal definition, kinda like the resource fork of a mac file -- compiling your **DDS** specifications to create an empty file. **crtpf** ( create physical file ) and **dltf** ( delete file ) and **clrpfm** ( empty physical file member ) and **crtdupobj** ( create duplicate object )  -- all come to mind.

About 20 minutes of planning and editing.

****remember****

Just type a command on the command line of your menu screen and press **F4 to get a wizard** for entering the command parameters, press **F1 for additional help** display.

****play safe****

Most commands refer to **library**, don't leave the **library** parameter **blank**.

You will be doing all of your work within what they call a **library** ( sort of a home folder ) storing your source code inside of **source members** inside of **source files** inside of your **library** ( sort of member equals pc file and source file and library are folders ).

***DON"T*** go defaulting to **library**  **qgpl**  or **qsys** or any other system **libraries**.  **PDM** and **crtlib** ( create library ) and **crtsrcpf** (create source physical file ) come to mind.

After you have a file to work with, then you can use any one of two products, either query or data file utility ( **DFU** ). Access either one with **wrkqry** or **wrkdfu** or  **strdfu**.  Again google or use ibm's website search in the iseries area of the online manuals to find books for these two products. They both have wizard-style screens to walk through to setup either a qry or dfu to process your file.

About another 20 minutes of setup, if you know what you're doing.

Both will let you create a module ( qry or dfu ) to work with your previously defined file to perform dumb keypunch entry and simple listing or with qry more sophisticated reports -- like a query to list records with missing data in fields or filtering for anticipated bad data.

Not to mention **strsql** ( start **SQL** ). But, that's another question and set of manuals. Yet, if you know one **sql**, you know them all.

If you need or prefer the pc environment, there is hope.

If access has been configured, if staff access the system with pc terminal emulators like **tn5250**, then you can also with additional setup of authorizations, use **ftp** to upload or download data from your file(s).  As long as you **DO NOT** use fancy fields like **binary format** or **packed format** for your numeric data -- then **ftp** will be good enough to translate your data as **plain text** from the **ibm ebcdic** to your **pc ascii** without screwing with your data.

***gotcha***

Internally within the file, negative numbers have the **units position overlaid** to indicate negativity so that digit will appear as a letter while positive numbers will be fine.

****fall back plan****

If you don't care to mess with qry and dfu -- then you may be able to use a pc spreadsheet !!

BUT, you still need to do the **library** and **source physical files** thing, and the **DDS** thing and **crtpf**.

You may use, setup and configure **odbc** if you don't care much for ftp.  With ***odbc*** active your file can be downloaded from your **library** into a Microsoft Excel  spreadsheet just fine, even the negative numbers!! And vice versa, upload a spreadsheet to your iseries file. The file's data definition directs how the  columns are treated as fields in a record.

Dates and time too yes, you can define a numeric field as a **date-time stamp** instead of a dumb 6 or 8 digit plain numeric.

If you're using ibm emulators to access your iseries then there is more that can be done from such a pc workstation with it's ibm pc suite for iseries access -- almost drag'n'drop data to or from your file with an equivalent to windows explorer interface.

Have fun. Stay thirsty.